# Insert file name into text

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I know how to get file names from a directory [1]

Each file name will have <rep_data></rep_data>. What i would like to do is find the file name and for that file name find the tag </rep_data> and add the file name to it and repeat

So if I have 2 files in my directory:
ABC.xml
WoW.xml

for the A.XML which has <rep_data></rep_data> contents add the file name so the contents is <rep_data>ABC is the File Name</rep_data>

for the B.XML which has <rep_data></rep_data> contents add the file name so the contents is <rep_data>Wow is the File Name</rep_data>

[1]

```
# import OS module
import os
 
# Get the list of all files and directories
path = "C:\Temp\FileNames"
dir_list = os.listdir(path)
 
print("Files and directories in '", path, "' :")
 
# prints all files
print(dir_list)
```

Comment: Which is the problem/question? And why is pycharm and jupyter as post's tags?

Comment: so you need to open each file, read its contents as XML, update the text of the rep_data tag to the file name, and then write the XML back to the same file?

Comment: @Kurt basically write the file name inside the contexts of the xml document in between the rep_data tag...

Comment: You can't just write new characters to a file, you will be overwriting the characters in those positions resulting in invalid xml.  You will need to do basically what I said.  Read the file as XML, update the XML, then write the XML back to the same path.  Look up "reading xml in python" and give it a shot, then come back with any problems